# calculating values in Linq deferred linq statment

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to optimize this piece of code this piece of code takes about 50 seconds to call. what this needs to do is get a total score from item.score and the achieved score from item.score if condition.isFound == false. Any help you guys can give would be fantastic

```
var myscore = from inspection in roomInspections
            from RoomItemInspection in db.Table<RoomItemInspection>()
                where RoomItemInspection.roomInspectionId == inspection.id
            from RoomItemConditionInspection condition in db.Table<RoomItemConditionInspection>()
                where condition.roomItemInspectionId == RoomItemInspection.id
            from FloorRoom floorRoom in db.Table<FloorRoom>()
                where floorRoom.id == RoomItemInspection.roomItemId
            from room myRoom in db.Table<room>()
                where myRoom.id == floorRoom.roomId
            from RoomItem roomItem in db.Table<RoomItem>()
                where roomItem.roomId == myRoom.id
            from item myItem in db.Table<item>()
                where myItem.id == roomItem.itemId
            select new {score = myItem.Score, isFound = condition.isFound};

//This is the slow part of the code
totalScore = myscore.Sum (s => s.score);
        score = myscore.Sum (s => s.isFound ? s.score : 0);

        if(totalScore == 0)
            return 0;
        score = score / totalScore * 100f;
        return score = (float)Math.Round (score, 1);
```

Here are the classes involved

```
public class room
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PKId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
}

public class RoomItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PKId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int roomId { get; set; }
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public bool isHidden { get; set; }
    public bool isAlways { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
}

public class item
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PKId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
}

public class RoomItemConditionInspection
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PKId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int conditionId { get; set; }
    public int roomItemInspectionId { get; set; }
    public bool isFound { get; set; }
    public bool isSynced { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Join` to link the tables? This could be  more efficient, most likely  if collections are involved, so in `Linq-To-Objects`.

Comment: You shuld join by fields with PK, FK, or indexses. In your code you do joins by simple fields, without indexes, thats leeds to full scan of decart multiplication of your tables

Comment: -1 It is unclear what type of `Linq` you are using. Without know that it is impossible to optimise the query for you. Although it looks like its `LinqToSQL` which is likely the problem.

Comment: I agree, we don't know the database and the table definitions or whether you use Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework. Any answer you get would just be a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shuld join by fields with PK, FK, or indexses. In your code you do joins by simple fields, without indexes, thats leeds to full scan of decart multiplication of your tables